# In my testNG integration tests can I use @factory more than once (using Jenkins and Maven for my builds)?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng, factory

**What - Detailed Steps**

1. My test calls a 3rd party API and sends a request for a new transaction (let's say I need to do this for 5 tests which were generated by @Factory). These tests end here with the status of 'Pending'.
2. The 3rd party API takes 5 minutes to process the data. I need to make a second call to the API after 5 minutes (for all my pending tests) to get the transaction ID for my request and then pass/fail the test.
3. I want to spin up another @Factory here to re-generate all the Pending tests. These pending tests call the API again (with different inputs) to get the transaction ID and pass/fail the test based on this info.

**How**

I am trying to use `@Factory` to generate a bunch of tests dynamically and run them. After these tests are run I want to use `@Factory` again to generate a second batch of new tests and run them. The problem is, I did not have success when trying to call `@Factory` for the second time.

I am using Jenkins and Maven in my setup for generating builds and that is when I would want the tests to run.

**Questions**

Is step 3 possible?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish, without using technical details, about what you have tried. Sounds not logical, what you do. So some more background is needed, to answer this question.

Comment: Verhagen, my tests are more of integration tests than unit tests. My mistake.

1. My test calls a 3rd party API and sends a request for a new transaction (let's say I need to do this for 5 tests which were generated by @Factory). These tests end here with the status of 'Pending'.

2. The 3rd party API takes 5 minutes to process the data. I need to make a second call to the API after 5 minutes (for all my pending tests) to get the transaction ID for my request and then pass/fail the test.

3. I want to spin up another @Factory here to re-generate all the Pending tests.

Is step 3 possible?

Comment: No issue, you can create integration tests with TestNG as well. But without a better background it is hard to see / understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: __Q:__ _In point 2: 3th party API call_ takes 5min. Does it come back after these 5min? Or does the call return immediatly, just the process in the backgruond takes (about) 5min?

Comment: The API responds with a 'request ID' as soon as I send my transaction request. Then it takes around 5 minutes in their environment to process the data I sent. I make a second call to the API after 5 minutes (with different parameters) to get the status of the Request ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Responses to this question led me in finding the answer - Thanks @Verhagen

1. I added 2 tests in my testng.xml.
2. And have 2 factories setup in my code.
3. When a build is triggered,

   ```
   @Factory 1 creates tests --> 
   @Factory 2 creates more tests --> 
   tests by @Factory 1 are executed --> 
   tests by @Factory 2 are executed
   ```

This solves my requirement for running a batch of tests (first batch) and then running a second batch of tests based on the out come of the first batch.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the extra comment / improves question, it sounds indeed like an *Integration Test*.

There are some need *Integration Test* libraries like [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/), [Serenity](http://www.thucydides.info/#/), [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm), etc which would probably better for setting this up.

With TestNG, you could create 3 tests, where each next test depends on the previous test. See code sample below, from [testng dependency test](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-7-dependency-test/)

```
package com.mkyong.testng.examples.dependency;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class App {

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("This is method 1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("This is method 2");
    }

}
```

*Here the most simple dependency is show. See the sample code for more complex cases, like groups etc. For setting up two test classes each with their own `@Factory`*

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I will consider your other options. 

Have you tried using @Factory twice? Is that possible?

Comment: @Nash, No never tried that. Maybe I'll give it a try as some mini example. I'll keep you updated, if I get it working or not.

Comment: @Nash __Q:__ Are you using any build tool, like Ant, Maven, Gradle ?

Comment: Yep, added that in one of the edits "I am using Jenkins and Maven in my setup for generating builds". Thanks for trying @Verhagen!

Comment: I added 2 tests in my testng.xml . This is what happens, @ Factory 1 creates tests  --> @ Factory 2 creates tests --> tests by @ Factory 1 are executed --> tests by @ Factory 2 are executed

Comment: But I need it to work in this order @ Factory 1 creates tests --> tests by @ Factory 1 are executed --> @ Factory 2 creates tests --> tests by @ Factory 2 are executed.

Comment: __Q:__ Why are the steps 1, 2 and 3, not done inside a single test ? Sounds little like: __1__ prepare the test; __2__ run the test; __3__ do some validation checking.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 make up the 'first test' and step 3 makes up the 'second test'. This is because there is a wait of 5 minutes after step 2. 
Rather than waiting for the 5 minutes and sitting idle, I would like to run my other tests after step 2 and then perform step 3 later.